# How to reduce the code generated by protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

protobuf compiler generates so many methods for every single field in .proto file.Is it possible to make it to generate only (for ex: required string name=1;) set_name(const char* value) and name() only in c++.

Answer (score 3):

In your .proto file, set `option optimize_for = ***;` to either `CODE_SIZE`, or `LITE_RUNTIME`.

The `CODE_SIZE` option implements the same API as the default, with smaller lib sizes. However, the `LITE_RUNTIME` implements a subset of the full lib. It does not support descriptors or reflection. The difference is given here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#message

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no option for this.

Note that most of the methods are inline. Inline methods that you don't use will be dropped by the compiler and not included in the output binary. So the only real problem with having so many methods is that it might make compilation slower.